# Changing IIS bindings with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I was looking to move web binding port from one site to another using PowerShell on Windows 21012 R2.

After looking online I found the command

```
Set-WebBinding -Name 'work' -BindingInformation "*:80:" -PropertyName Port -Value 1234
```

Now the command is from a MS blog but everytime I run the command I get the following error.

> WARNING: Target configuration object '/system.applicationHost/sites/site[compare-string-ordinal(@name,'work',true())=0]/bindings/binding[(@protocol='http' or @protocol='https') and compare-string-ordinal(@bindingInformation,'*:80:',true())=0] is not found at path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'

Now for the life of me cannot understand why it's not finding the site "work":

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WebBinding -Port 80 -Name "work"

protocol        bindingInformation        sslFlags
--------        ------------------        --------
http            :80:work                         0
```

These are clean sites created by PowerShell that also creates an application pool of the same name.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but this is how I fixed it:

```
Set-WebBinding -Name 'work' -BindingInformation ":80:" -PropertyName Port -Value 1234
```

The `-BindingInformation` should be the same as what you see with the `Get-WebBinding` command.